# Why $ax+by=c$ divides the plane in two half planes characterized by inequalities

Tags: inequality, plane-geometry

The line $ax+by=c$ divides the plane into two half planes given by $ax+by<c$ and $ax+by>c$. My question is why all points in the any fixed half plane will satisfy exactly one of these inequalities.

Comment: What is your definition of half-plane?

Comment: @lhf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_(geometry)

Comment: @Shahab: the definition of the half-planes you refer to is precisely what you are inquiring about. So the answer is trivially that all points in a half plane satisfy the inequality because a half plane is the set of points that satisfy the inequality. You should give us another definition to avoid the circularity.

Comment: I meant the first paragraph of the link: In geometry, a half-space is either of the two parts into which a plane divides the three-dimensional Euclidean space. More generally, a half-space is either of the two parts into which a hyperplane divides an affine space. That is, the points that are not incident to the hyperplane are partitioned into two convex sets (i.e., half-spaces), such that any subspace connecting a point in one set to a point in the other must intersect the hyperplane.

Comment: A half plane is defined analogously in 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x,y)=ax+by-c$ is positive on one side of the line and negative on the other by the intermediate value theorem.

If $f(x_1,y_1)$ is negative and  $f(x_2,y_2)$ is positive, then the value of $f$ on the line segment joining $A=(x_1,y_1)$ and $B=(x_2,y_2)$ must be zero somewhere, so the line segment must cross $ax+by=c$.

(Given that everything is "linear," you can actually find the point on the line between A and B that hits $ax+by=c$, so you don't technically need IVT, but IVT shows the same thing about more general functions $f$ - if you subtract the points where $f(X)=0$, then the remaining points will partition into "connected components" on which $f$ is either strictly positive or strictly negative.)

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask a follow up question related to this here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you understand why every point on a one dimensional numberline is either greater than or less than (or equal to) a defined point on that numberline?

If so, then imagine the $xy$ plane as just an infinite collection of vertical numberlines. And the dividing point on each numberline is defined by some function of $x$.  So every point on the plane falls on one (and only one) of these numberlines and must be on one side or the other of it.

Comment: Can you make your argument more rigorous? (Intuitively it is clear) Why will all points on the same half plane be all less than (or greater then) the dividing point?